# Slider image using only css: animation + transition at once

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm working on creating a Slider image, using animation and transition at once. the animation property translates a div(.slider__images) to the left almost every 6.5 sec and the transition property works when the user clicks the small rounded button to translate the Slider  to the left with a specific value. But the problem is I can't use both of them it's simply does not work, I need to comment one of them to make the animation or the buttons work. You can have a look at the code on codepen: https://codepen.io/Youssri/pen/GbajOQ?editors=1100
NOTE: the animation is on comment, try to uncomment it... it won't work!

This is the keyframe animation:

```
@keyframes slider {
  0% { 
    left: 0; 
  }
  20% { 
    left: 0; 
  }
  40% { 
    left:  -100vw; 
  }
  60%{
    left: -100vw;
  }
  80%{
    left: -200vw;
  }
  100% {
    left: -200vw;
  }
}
```

This the buttons css

```
#first-image:target ~ .slider__images {
  left: 0;
}
#second-image:target ~ .slider__images {
  left: -100vw;
}
#third-image:target ~ .slider__images {
  left: -200vw;
}
```

the div to slide

```
.slider__images {
  width: 300vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 2s;
  /*animation: slider 20s infinite alternate;*/
}
```

Comment: use translate with the  animation and left with transition